# Is it possible to run an App before the "Android is starting..." prompt?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set an .apk file to start running before everything else?

I'm using a Re-mapper app for my broken Recent Apps button, however it takes sometime after boot to kick in. Is there anyway I can make it a priority over all other apps (no root access).

I'm also open to any other suggestions too!

Thanks!

Comment: you want your app to run before bootup?... no

Comment: Yes or be a priority over other apps. Is there any way I can delay other apps so the re-mapper can start first?

Comment: No you can not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. By removing the bloatware (https://www.howtogeek.com/115533/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-android-bloatware/) off my phone, I have significantly decreased boot up time thus allowing my Remapper app to kick in faster.

Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation with broken keys!

Thanks